# What's the name of this electrolysis device?

Tags: electrochemistry

I've seen it in a couple of videos, it's used to electrolyze water in 2 different containers at the same time to make a comparison and thus is very handy.

What is it called (besides just a hydrolizer)? 
[image: http://i1274.photobucket.com/albums/y432/mocDOTtekcubotohp/hydrolizer_zps38a63656.jpg]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a precipitator, also known as TDS indicator.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this article](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/elan.201100346/abstract), in which the authors describe a system that can do 25 cells simultaneously, the term 'Parallel Electrolyser' would seem appropriate.